# App spends unexpected amount of time in background

Tags: ios, energy

According to Battery screen in Settings, my app uses 13 times more time in background than in foreground. This is totally unexpected, because the app is a news app.

How can I find out what the app does in the background?

The app has "Audio, AirPlay, and Picture-in-Picture" background mode enabled. It is used to play radio on request. But the unexpected amount of time in background is spent even when radio is not used.

The app subscribes to location updates (when app is in use). There are dependencies like Google Mobile Ads, Hockeyapp, Firebase, and others.

It looks like some of the dependencies might do more than expected. But how I can find what exactly causes app to use such large amount of energy?

Comment: Did you verify that you are not getting any silent push notification or push notification

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya The app can receive push notifications. Can you please elaborate on your answer? I am not sure how push notifications and abnormal amount of work in background are connected.

Comment: My point is when you receive a push notification system starts your application in background for a purpose  in that time app can fetch fresh data from server and when user opens your app he got that fresh data, also system schedules time to open your app in background matched with user time table of using your app,

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Thank you! I will have a look into this possible cause.